# Rename-computer Name has spaces

Tags: string, windows, powershell, scripting

I need to write a script to rename a laptop with LT- the serial number from the bios.

I am able to get it to do all of that stuff except the rename part.

It seems that this is because a variable has length 14 and most of that is spaces.

Here is the script, can anyone help?

```
clear-host
$name = wmic bios get serialnumber
$name = $name[2]
$computername = "LT-" + "$name"
$computername.replace(' ','')
Rename-Computer -NewName $computername
```

Thanks,

Dark

Comment: `(gwmi win32_bios).SerialNumber`. `wmic` is a command-line tool you generally don't need or want in PowerShell, since it has direct support for WMI.

Comment: Using your approach - you could have used     `$computername.trim()` instead of the     `replace()` method to remove the spaces

Comment: `Rename-Computer -NewName ($computername.replace(' ',''))` as a string which the `replace` method is applied to is not affected.

Comment: `$CN = "LT-$(GWMI Win32_Bios).SerialNumber)" -replace '\s'` This will build your string and remove whitespace in one line.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 following `"LT-$` there is an opening parenthesis missing.

Comment: @LotPings Yes it is.  Can't edit it anymore

Comment: Could you supply what output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
$serial = Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
Rename-Computer -NewName LT-$serial.replace(' ','')
```

That should do it.